# Is $M= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x \in \mathbb{N} \lor y \in \mathbb{N}\} $ polygonally connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, connections

I'm trying to prove that $M= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} : x \in \mathbb{N} \lor y \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is polygonally connected.

I know that polygonally connected implies arc-connected so if I prove that for an $x, y \in M$  there is no arc $\varphi$ joining x and y that verifies $\varphi(t) \in A$ $ \forall t \in [a,b]$ then it won't be polygonally connected, but I'm not quite sure how I could prove it or if I'm taking the wrong path.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you drawn a picture of $M$ and got an idea of how polygonal paths between points might look like?

Comment: @Christoph $\mathbb{R^2} $ \ $\{ (x,y) :  x \land y \notin \mathbb{N} \}$

Comment: What does $M$ *look like*?

Comment: @Christoph Like continuous lines formed, in pieces, by segments parallel to the axes where $x \lor y \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: So it's like a grid. Do you see how to walk from one point to another on this grid?

Comment: @Christoph It depends on where the point are,  If both points are on the same line of the grid, it is enough to join them and if not, you could go to the line where it is through the points where $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ be points in $M$ and let $g(x)=\max(0,\lfloor x\rfloor)$. Note that $g(n)=n$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $g(x)\in\mathbb N$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ and hence the following polygonal chain is completely contained in $M$:
$$
(x,y) \to (g(x), y) \to (g(x), g(y)) \to(g(x'),g(y)) \\\to (g(x'), g(y')) \to (g(x'), y') \to (x',y').
$$